# calculate time from strings in dropdown lists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 dropdown lists holding times in 24 hour format, going up in increments of 5 minutes eg 00:00, 00:05, 00:10. Both lists are displaying strings

When a user selects a start and end time using these, I want to calculate the time difference but I'm not sure how to convert the format I have in the lists to workable times, can anyone help?

Im using C# in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Just parse them to `TimeSpan` and calculate their difference with `-` operator. Would be better to see your work as well.

Comment: You have two characters of hour, two characters of minute in a string and there's `Substring` available...

Comment: Theresa, I closed your question as a duplicate. Please read _that_ link carefully. You just need to get selected values for your dropdownlists and parse them to `TimeSpan` and get their differences. Then you can get their second, minute, hour representations with it's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will show you an example of how to do this:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("00:00");
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("00:05");
TimeSpan s1 = d2-d1;
Console.WriteLine(s1.TotalMinutes + " minutes difference");
```

You can replace the strings "00:00", and "00:05" with the values from the dropdown lists, and calculate the timespan between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(ddl1.SelectedValue, "HH:mm",DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(ddl2.SelectedValue, "HH:mm",DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
TimeSpan diff = dt2 - dt1;
```

Now you have all you need in the `TimeSpan`, f.e.:

```
int hours = diff.Hours;      // 0 - 23
int minutes = diff.Minutes;  // 0 - 59
int totalMinutes = (int) diff.TotalMinutes;
```